# RxJS: Accessing a previous value further down the pipe chain

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the below code

```
updateProduct$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UPDATE_PRODUCT),
    mergeMap(updateProduct => 
      this.productService.put(updateProduct.product, updateProduct.id).pipe(
        map((product) => PRODUCT_DETAILS_COMPONENT(product)), // want to access updateProduct here 
        catchError((error) => of(PRODUCT_ERROR(error)))
      )
    )
  )
);
```

In the `map((product) => PRODUCT_DETAILS_COMPONENT(product))` I want to access the previous value of `updateProduct`

Comment: your `map` is in the inner observable you should already be able to access updateProduct no?

Comment: I can confirm what @FanCheung said - I do this all the time in my effects.

Comment: @deaks I am not sure about the syntax, how can I access, can you please show me the example

Comment: In your line `map((product) => PRODUCT_DETAILS_COMPONENT(product))`, you can simply pass `updateProduct` to your action.

Comment: @FanCheung may be yes, I am not sure how to do that, can you please post an example

Comment: @deaks how can I pass updateProduct to the action, quite not sure

Comment: You have your action you wish to call. You are currently passing in your `product` object. Instead of this object, pass in the `updateProduct` object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understand you correctly, but at first glance it looks exactly like a use case for [pairwise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/pairwise) operator.
Could be used like this:

```
 this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UPDATE_PRODUCT),
    pairwise(),
    mergeMap([previousUptProd, currentUptProd] => {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updatedProduct` as param in `PRODUCT_DETAILS_COMPONENT` in your inner observable

```
 this.productService.put(updateProduct.product, updateProduct.id).pipe(
        map((product) => PRODUCT_DETAILS_COMPONENT(updateProduct)), // want to access updateProduct here 
        catchError((error) => of(PRODUCT_ERROR(error)))
      )
```